Chrome 124 hangs, doesn't attach to wayland
Running 23.10 on Dell XPS 9550 with latest Ubuntu updates. Recently I upgraded Chrome to 124 (123 worked fine) Now Chrome hangs on startup. By hangs, I mean it never displays on Wayland and makes Wayland very slow.
This are the errors in syslog.

[9947:9947:0417/155837.646934:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not part of the idle inhibition specification: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/idle-inhibit-spec/latest/
Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Attempting to use a delegate that only supports static-sized tensors with a graph that has dynamic-sized tensors (tensor#141 is a dynamic-sized tensor).

System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-04-17 16:17:31

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Dell Inc. XPS 15 9550
Memory:                                      16.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ × 8
Graphics:                                   Intel® HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2)
Disk Capacity:                               (null)

Software Information:

Firmware Version:**                            1.15.0
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 23.10
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               45.2
Windowing System:                            Wayland
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.5.0-27-generic

I tried reinstall, no joy...
It does not run from the command line or launcher.
Update:
ran in command line
google-chrome --ozone-platform=wayland  <-- This worked !!!
(made sure chrome://flags Preferred Ozone platform was set to wayland)
I changed /usr/share/applications/usr/share/google-chrome.desktop to run with --ozone-platform=wayland did not work from launcher.
I assume it must be something with attaching to the Wayland server.

I have the same issue on Fedora Kinoite

see the issue on the bug tracker : https://issues.chromium.org/issues/329678163

Reported as a bug at https://issues.chromium.org/issues/329678163

Start with: (from your bin directory)
google-chrome --ozone-platform=wayland

or
google-chrome-stable --ozone-platform=wayland

or
brave --ozone-platform=wayland

then go to chrome://flags and set ozone back to "Default".
It takes X11 and flickers, but works from the link or icon.

That worked !! thanks !!!

I needed to set the chrome://flags to X11 instead of default, but otherwise everything else in the comment worked for me.

I tried google-chrome-stable --ozone-platform=wayland
and got:
[174120:174120:0928/163700.761390:ERROR:wayland_connection.cc(203)] Failed to connect to Wayland display: No such file or directory (2)
[174120:174120:0928/163700.761450:ERROR:ozone_platform_wayland.cc(264)] Failed to initialize Wayland platform
[174120:174120:0928/163700.761459:ERROR:env.cc(258)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
